# Deploying new contract to etherium network with web3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, web3js

I have tried to run this code with relevant dependencies to get contract address and I received an error

`No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.` from the browser. Additionally, there is no error while deploying with the Remix tool by using metamask ropsten testnet.

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: '' }); 
    try {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log(accounts)
        await factory.methods
        .createCampaign(this.state.minimumContribution)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] })
        Router.pushRoute('/');
    } catch (err) {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message }) 
    }
    this.setState({ loading: false });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of how you set up web3?

Comment: ```import Web3 from 'web3';

let web3;

if ( typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.eth !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else { 
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/741b62b06288435e856e8567767a3a5b'
    );
    web3 = new Web3(provider);
}

export default web3;```

Answer (score 0):

Does `console.log(accounts)` print anything?

If not, try to set up web3 with the following code:

```js
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  web3.currentProvider.enable();
} else {
  window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("..."));
}
```